# Need to create element using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I want to create a Element in xml `<a:ln w="12700">` using xslt 1.0.

and this is what i did in xslt

```
<xsl:variable name="width-value">12700</xsl:variable>
<xsl:element name="a:ln">
     <xsl:attribute name="w">
          <xsl:value-of select="$width-value"/>
     </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:element>
```

its throwing error,

```
You cannot call an attribute 'w'' 
FATAL ERROR:  'Could not compile stylesheet' javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Could not compile stylesheet
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:825)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTransformer(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:614)
        at com.vignesh.main.convert(main.java:288)
        at com.vignesh.main.main(main.java:70)
```

Comment: Don't see why your java implementation is complaining from just this code, as w is a valid attribute name, so can you give more? Incidentally, the code you give is equivalent to the much simpler `<xsl:variable name="width-value">12700</xsl:variable>
<a:ln w="{$width-value}"/>`

Comment: I tried this. but the output doesn't contains attribute(only the element is creating).

Comment: Have you tried taking a sample of the input XML and using the XSLT with a browser? Even just a different error message might be informative, but I can't see anything wrong in just the fragment you give, and MarcoS' answer suggests they can't either.

Comment: Are you trying to use apostrophe in the name as in `w'`?

Comment: @Alejandro I think that might be it, I just came here because it occurred to me that perhaps they'd used a different name in their example than their real code as that could, depending on the name, cause this error. Certainly, `w'` isn't an allowed attribute name.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that I see is that you're missing the namespace declaration for `a`: If I have to make this snippet working, I must add something like this

```
<xsl:element name="a:ln" namespace="http://www.example.com/a/">
```

Perhaps you have the `a` namespace declaration elsewhere. I suspect the problem is due to some other part of your XSL, because this snippet looks OK to me.